# iOS Auto-Layout Stretch to Fill

Tags: ios, user-interface, interface-builder, autolayout

I would like to take 4 square UIImageViews and align them from left to right at the bottom of a view.  I want the images to grow in height (with the correct height/width aspect ratio) and have no spaces between the images.   I want all the images to be of equal width

I seem to be having a hard time coming up with the proper constraints.

I've set all the images to Aspect Fit.  I've created 8 constraints on all 4 images to have equal widths and height.  On the far left and far right I've set the training space to the view as 0.  I've aligned them all to the bottom of the view with a constraint of 0 as well.

This all seems to work... except that the images only grow in width and not height.  I'm 
hoping that as the width is calculated the image will grow proportionally in height.  Any ideas?

PS: I would like to do this in Interface Builder if possible, but if code is needed, that's fine

Comment: Are you sure no constraints conflict with another, and therefore dropped?

Comment: Yeah, I must have had a conflict that I didn't notice.  I scraped the layout and started over.  Then I put my images all inside a new UIView.  Everything seemed to work the second time... but man... autolayout is frustrating at times!

Comment: It is. I always end up adding all constraints in code :-)